# How to draw moving text with GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

The task is to draw a moving text on a black background (for example, a moving number) with .NET GDI+. Some other elements may present on this background, so it isn't possible to fill all the area with black and then draw a string in a new position.

My current code is as follows:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
// drawing a string
Font myFont = new Font("Fixedsys", 10);
g.DrawString("1", myFont, Brushes.Gray, 100, 100);
// erasing a string
g.DrawString("1", myFont, Brushes.Black, 100, 100);

// then we repeat the code above with a new position for a string
```

The problem is that the text isn't erased entirely by the second DrawString with black brush. Small border remains visible. Please help, how to remove this trace, and draw moving text correctly.

Comment: This problem got started by you using CreateGraphics(), the method that launched a thousand questions.  Actually okay for rapid painting.  But with the quirk that you no longer get the benefit of OnPaintBackground() so you are drawing on pixels that were already drawn.  They are not the exact same pixels because of anti-aliasing so you will not 'erase' the previous ones.  You reliable erase with the same thing that OnPaintBackground() does: Graphics.FillRectangle().  You now get flicker, you have to do the same thing that the DoubleBuffered property does.  Still no use for CreateGraphics :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding the following:

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;
```